# convert String to XML in VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

```
Dim filter As String
filter = 'Bal_ln_id = 110 and Bal_ln_id = 100'     
Dim xmldoc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
xmldoc.LoadXml(filter)
```

I am simply trying to convert a string in to xml file in VB.net.I am getting an xmlException `'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.'`

Am I missing something?

I am expecting the output as

```
<DocumentElement>
  <DATA_TABLE>
    <BAL_LN_ID>110</BAL_LN_ID>
  </DATA_TABLE>
  <DATA_TABLE>
     <BAL_LN_ID>100</BAL_LN_ID>
  </DATA_TABLE>
</DocumentElement>'
```

Comment: Yes you are, that string is certainly not xml. What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: I want to pass this as a parameter to the stored proc and thus I want to convert it in to XML. Something similar to <DocumentElement>
  <DATA_TABLE>
    <BAL_LN_ID>110</BAL_LN_ID>
  </DATA_TABLE>
  <DATA_TABLE>
     <BAL_LN_ID>100</BAL_LN_ID>
  </DATA_TABLE>
</DocumentElement>'

Comment: OK, well to create xml look at the xmlTextWriter class. There is no method that will automatically create xml from a string like yours, you will have to build it

Comment: How would VB or the XML class know what element tags you wanted?  Let alone how to parse an undefined expression language?

Comment: How are you creating the 'filter' string in the 1st place? In your example to just type it, but presumably you are creating it from some variables?

Answer (score 7):

To do this using the `XmlTextWriter` class, you could do something like this:

```
Private Function GenerateXml(ByVal ids As List(Of String)) As String
    Dim stringWriter As New StringWriter()
    Dim xmlWriter As New XmlTextWriter(stringWriter)
    xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument()
    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("DocumentElement")
    For Each id As String In ids
        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("DATA_TABLE")
        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("BAL_LN_ID")
        xmlWriter.WriteString(id)
        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
    Next
    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
    xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument()
    Return stringWriter.ToString()
End Function
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
Dim ids As New List(Of String)()
ids.Add("110")
ids.Add("100")
Dim xml As String = GenerateXml(ids)
```